# Unreachable code, 2 iframes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `iframe` elements in one page. If `iframe` one is updated, the `src` attribute of `iframe` two should be updated to another address.

I have the following code: http://pastebin.com/zhRUwLu8

I get the error:

> Uncaught reference error: update is not defined

If I try it without the update I get this: http://pastebin.com/74h2bAFH

And triggers the error:

> Uncaught type error: cannot set property 'src' of null

How do I make this code reachable?

Answer (score 0):

`updateChat` is called when the `iframe` with the id `friends` is loaded, so the `iframe` with the id `chat` is still unknowen to the browser. Try calling `updateChat` once the chat-`iframe` has loaded.

```
<iframe id="chat" onLoad="updateChat(...);">
```

Comment: This ain't the problem. The problem is that chat isn't recognized by the script. As it is created after the script. But if i place the script underneath it, the function won't exist anymore.